# How can I define the targets of columnDefs in datatables as "last"?

Tags: jquery, datatables, target, columndefinition

My target is right now set to column 5:

```
"columnDefs": [{
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
    return data;
  },
  "targets": 5
}],
```

What I want to do is, instead of targeting it to a specific number, I want to target it to the last column.

What I need is something like this:

```
"columnDefs": [{
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
    return data;
  },
  "targets": last
}],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) you can provide an integer for the `targets` which specifies the index of the column to use.

> This `columnDefs.targets` option provides the information required by DataTables for which columns in the table the column definition object should be applied.
>
> It can be:
>
> - 0 or a positive integer - column index counting from the left
> - A negative integer - column index counting from the right
> - A string - class name will be matched on the TH for the column (without a leading .)
> - The string "_all" - all columns (i.e. assign a default)

Note the second point; you can provide a negative integer to start the index from the right, so `-1` would be the last column.

```js
"columnDefs": [{
  "render": function(data, type, row) {
    return data;
  },
  "targets": -1
}],
```

Comment: The string "_all" - all columns (i.e. assign a default), what is the default number of columns? is it first 10 columns?

Comment: I don't know without seeing the source of Datatables, however it says 'all', so I have no reason to think it would be anything other than every column you've defined.